# How to debug using Karate UI when calling a feature file from another feature file

Tags: karate

I am trying to debug with Karate UI, when calling a feature file from my feature file `Eg: App.run("src/test/java/demo/cats/cats.feature", "dev");`

When calling dogs.feature in the cats.feature file, how should I debug cats.feature. 
When I start UI with the feture file path example above, it fails as I am calling another feature file.

> Error:javascript evaluation failed

Comment: Sorry for the Typo's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the UI, I recommend you use the JUnit HTML report to troubleshoot tests. Step-through debugging is quite hard - especially if you are a non-programmer.

Note that you can use the `print` statement within a test to log the values of variables to make it easier to troubleshoot. Take a look at this video: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/935029435140489216